# How do I disable form validation for ng-click?

Tags: angularjs, validation, required, angularjs-ng-click

I have a form where certain inputs have "required" attribute. I also have a button that adds form fields when clicked, but it always triggers the form validation message when the required fields are not filled out. I only want form validation to trigger for ng-submit and not ng-click. Is this possible?

Comment: use `type="button"` of button...!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you have a look at the W3C specification, it would seem like the obvious thing to try is to mark your button elements with type='button' when you don't want them to submit.

The thing to note in particular is where it says

A button element with no type attribute specified represents the same thing as a button element with    its type attribute set to "submit"

Comment: Ah, the problem was I didn't specify a type="" for my button and it defaulted to submit.

Answer (score 2):

when you do not want submission on specific button then define type="button". it will 100% work

Comment: Hi jitendra - this is the same solution as already suggested by Amit Sharma. Do you have any different advice?

Answer (score 0):

Use `novalidate` for your form:

```
<form name="aForm" novalidate>
```

or use ng-form instead:

```
<div ng-form name="aForm">
```

Check [this link](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/validations.html) for further info about form validation in AngularJS.